# Get a single value form a serial SQL entry

Tags: mysql

how to I get the single values from an entry like this:

```
O:8:"stdClass":10:     
{s:4:"mime";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:4:"size";s:6:"238062";s:7:"storage";s:9:"FSStorage";     s:3:"uri";s:26:"kat_bild_mountainbikes.jpg";s:8:"filename";s:26:"kat_bild_mountainbikes.jpg";s:5:"width";s:4:"1000";s:6:"height";s:3:"595";s:3:"alt";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:8:"settings";s:0:"";}
```

I want to get the image path, there. What is the best an fastest way, to do that?

Comment: This is why you shouldn't `serialize()` data in a table.

Comment: The fastest way would presumably be `unserialize()`

Answer (score 0):

REALLY bad idea to try to do it with SQL...

But if the structure of the serialized information is always the same, you "could" use substring_index...

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(<column>, '"',6),'"',-1) AS Image_Path
 FROM `<table>`
```

Simply replace `<column>` and `<table>` with the appropriate names...